# Dependency Inversion Principle

Tags: solid-principles, dependency-inversion

I'm trying to learn SOLID Principles and I am very confuse with this dependency Inversion principle.

Can someone explain and see if my code below violates the mentioned principle?

Sorry for the messy code. asking this through my phone.

```
interface IFact{

Public int FindFact();

}

Class Factorial1:IFact{

//Itretive implementation for finding factorial

}

Class Factorial2:IFact{

//Recursive implementation for finding factorial

}

Class Factuser{

IFact fact;

Public FactUser(IFact f){

fact=f;

}
Public Calculate (int num){

Fact.findfact(num);

}




//Main method implementation
Main(){

Factuser obj=new Factuser(new Factorial2 ());
Int ans=obj.Calculate(5);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is going to be unconventional but that's probably what you are looking for since plenty of more academic answers exist.

At the end of the day, `Factuser` is dispatching `Factorial2` methods. It literally needs to access that part in memory where they are stored. We can say `Factuser` depends on `Factorial2` at runtime.

Had you implemented `Factuser` with no injection via the constructor, it would have had to mention the name of `Factorial2` in order to instantiate it and use it (and the other variant as well). In other words, `Factuser` would have depended on `Factorial2` in the source code as well. In such case we say the source code dependencies flow in the same direction as the runtime dependencies.

Instead, you made both `Factuser` and `Factorial2` mention the name of a common interface, `IFact`, which they both have to look up in their source code. What this achieves is decoupling `Factuser` from a specific implementation of `IFact`, and that's good. However, it doesn't mean `Factorial2` is now magically depending on `Factuser`. Indeed, programming to an interface on itself is not inverting anything, it's just adding an indirection.

The inversion happens if you split the code in different modules and you decide that the `IFact` interface is owned by the user module. This module doesn't need to mention any name from the outside world, so it doesn't depend on anything. On the other hand, the module containing `Factorial2` needs to import `IFact` from the user module and now depends on it. To sum it up: the implementations module depends on the user module, which is the opposite of the runtime dependency, we have our inversion.